# Why does root cron job script need 'sudo' to run properly?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, raspberry-pi

I'm running this simple script on my Raspberry Pi to auto update so I can forget about it. It also keeps a log that says whether the update was successful. The script is update.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Update starts on: $(date)" >> /home/pi/update.log
 if apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y; then
    echo "update successful $(date)"  >> /home/pi/update.log
 else
    echo "Couldn't update $(date)" >> /home/pi/update.log
 fi
```

I added this script to the root crontab by using `sudo crontab -e` and the cronjob is set to run every day at 6AM

```
0 6 * * * /home/pi/update.sh
```

I know that it works to some extent because running `sudo ./update.sh` in the shell manually runs the commands and leaves a "successful" entry in the log. On the other hand, when ran from the crontab, I always get the "couldn't update" entry. In case it matters, the "update.sh" script was created by the "pi" user and I never changed the permissions, except giving it execution permissions.

I read another question about the same problem and the guy solved it by putting a `sudo` in front of the command. He admits it's weird because it's already being executed by root, but says it works. I tried adding the `sudo` and verified it actually works now.

Does anyone know why this happens? Why does it need the `sudo` if it's already root?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this script fail when run from cron, but works when run manually?](http://superuser.com/questions/725623/why-does-this-script-fail-when-run-from-cron-but-works-when-run-manually)

Comment: I read that post and it gave a practical solution, but I don't think it gave an actual answer, not that I understood anyway. I rephrased the question to reflect that.

Comment: The environment for sudo and pure root are not necessarily the same. try typing `env` as root and then `sudo env` and compare the results.

Comment: It's like Windows UAC logged in as Administrator. Although you're logged in as the admin you are still just a normal user. To run a system function you have to "ask" for an admin token that gives you the ability to perform the task. This is the same for Linux (where, I believe, the idea originated) as it prevents the user accidentally doing something daft that could potentially ruin a system.

Comment: Does the failing `apt-get` command report any errors? Since you're not redirecting its output, it will be sent as mail to root.

Comment: Without clarification, there's the possibility that apt-get sees another apt-get instance in process (via lock files or whatever) and refuses to act because it can't "establish locks" (or whatever).

Answer (score 8):

Cron runs commands from a special shell, separate from the user or root shells. This shell does not have access to the same PATH variables as users. Therefore, when running a script as a cron job there are two  options:

A. Specify the full path for every command in the script (I.e. full path to aptitude- cron doesn't know where to look to find "apt-get")

B. Little trick I use- when writing the cron job line, even in the ROOT crontab, append sudo before the script path. This will trick cron into running the script from a root shell instead of the cron shell, which will give it access to all root's PATH variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the cron is running as your unprivileged user, and the `apt-get` commands require root (aka administration) elevation privileges to run.

An alternative is to run this command under the `root` user's crontab:

```
sudo -i
<type user password>
crontab -e
```

The first command elevates your entire shell to root and will also - crucially - give you access to root's environment, rather than just a single command as your user with elevated privileges.

The second command will edit the root crontab, not your own.